# Using search as main functionality on centre

Tags: usability, navigation, search, mobile-application, human-interface-guideline

Does using search in the center makes sense?

As users are used to using search from right corner.

[image: Search Bar]

Answer (score 5):

- I wouldn't mix [tabs](https://material.google.com/components/tabs.html#tabs-content) (where you are displaying pages/sections of your app) with search functionality.

  [image]
- [Don't mix icon labels and text labels](https://material.google.com/components/tabs.html#tabs-content) in the same tool bar:

  [image: Navigation with three items: 'All', a heart icon, and 'Recent']

  > **Don't**.
  >
  > Do not combine text labels with icons. Use either all text labels or all icon labels.
- Use the [App bar](https://material.google.com/layout/structure.html#structure-app-bar) for main App actions such as search:

  > The app bar, formerly known as the action bar in Android, is a special kind of toolbar that’s used for branding, navigation, search, and actions.
  >
  > (…)
  >
  > Icons on the right side of the app bar are app-related actions.

  [image]

Comment: I wonder if this is the same for other mobile OSes

Comment: @ecc There are similar conventions for [iOS](https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/ui-bars/navigation-bars/), you put the controls for key features on the right of the nav-bar

Answer (score 0):

There is absolutely nothing wrong with placing search in the middle. In many ways, this makes a lot of sense.

To a large extent, the [command + spacebar] use of search on a mac is very central, too.

Be that as it may, the icon is so obvious, and its contrast with the textual buttons so extreme, you're fine. No need to worry about "conventions" or "best practices". This is instantly understandable.

Comment: I agree, as an Android user I will have no problem to understand what it means, however I will be extremely _confused_ (no pun intended) if it won't display search in a tab page. After all conventions are useful to make our life easier, we're free to break them but there should be a good reason (which I can't see in this case)

Comment: What would be the gain from breaking this convention?